# Ajax Based Wizard Modal Box

Tags: jquery, cakephp, modal-dialog

I wanna create a Wizard style Ajax based modal box.

Ex: I wanna create a survey. I click Add Question. It opens a modal Box. I enter the Survey name and details. When i click next i want an Ajax Request to save the same into the database once its successful. i should be able to add questions and options in the same modal window.

Is there any jQuery based plugin i can use for the same ?

Ex: http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/ (this is in Prototype JavaScript Framework and script.aculo.us)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

The form is displayed as a modal iframe so the user can still see the underlying webpage. The forms can be handled as normal or as AJAX.